# How to get step machine id?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-step-functions

### Problem

The issue is that whenever the step functions fail we want to do to a couple of things.

1. Catch the error
2. Send a notification (including the exact reference of the failure)
3. Handle the error (reverse process)

Currently, the only information that is available in the request-id, whenever there is an exception/error inside the traceback, there is only a limited amount of information. As seen in this reference https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-context.html

Tried:

- The context variable
- Digging into boto3 to find a hacky solution
- Step function ResultSet data (*doesn't provide \w error id*)

---

**How to get** the exact stack reference and pass it to a lambda or access it within a lambda?

Comment: The `$$.Execution.Id` is available within stepfunction and can be passed to a lambda such that the lambda knows which stepfunction execution it belongs to. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-contextobject.html Not sure if that matches what you expect. Where exactly would you like an error to be handled? Within a lambda that is causing the error, or a dedicated lambda for error handling within the step function or some external lambda that gets trigged via some kind of monitoring?

Comment: Ok, @luk2302 I will review and try it, thanks.

Comment: Yes, we have a catcher, for errors. What it does is when there is an exception we call a lambda. That lambda has the functionality described above. Can we pass this Execution Id on exception?

Comment: @luk2302 it seems that yes, this is the right answer to get the step function id, however, there is no way to add it to the 'catcher' or the exception handler on the state machine. 
However, the catcher lambda can output this value ($$.Execution.Id) and then add another lambda to send the email.